# build elements hierarchy with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to set deep for each ul. I do

```
$('.topnav').find('ul').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('deep', $(this).index());
})
```

html

```
<ul class="topnav dropdown" >
    <li class="expand">
        <a href="/posluhy">Top</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li class="expand">
                <a href="/posluhy/metalocherepycja">Sub cat 1</a>
                <ul class="subnav">
                    <li >
                        <a href="/posluhy/metalocherepycja/dsafsadf">Sub Sub cat 1</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="expand">
                <a href="/posluhy/metalocherepycja">Sub cat 2</a>
                <ul class="subnav">
                    <li >
                        <a href="/posluhy/metalocherepycja/dsafsadf">Sub Sub cat 2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

but this make deep='1' for  each ul. I would like to get something like

```
1
  2
1
  2
```

Is that possible with jquery? Fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/GLjZt/1/

Comment: use `data-*` attributes instead of deprecated custom attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Index won't give you what you want, as it will only tell you where the element lies within a given set of elements; `$(this).index()` will always return 0. You need to calculate the depth based on the parent `ul`'s:

```
$('.topnav').find('ul').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('deep', $(this).parents('ul').length);//set attr deep
})
```